# Open a camera by clicking on the table view cell in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, camera

How to open a camera by clicking on the table view cell in an iPhone application?

Answer (score 1):

Use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in your table view delegate class. Instantiate a UIImagePickerController to show the camera, or photo selection dialog.

Make sure you call deselectRowAtIndexPath during the method call to deselect the row properly and comply with the UI guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the UITableView delegate methods and the UIImagePickerController in the documentation.